# How to use Wildcards with Firestore listeners? (On Snapshot)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to have a listener inside my app to check for document additions in something like this:

usersCol -> user1 -> collection1 -> **doc1** -> collectionToListen -> docAdded

usersCol -> user1 -> collection1 -> **doc2** -> collectionToListen -> docAdded

And so on. I basically want to hear every docAdded inside a collection inside DIFFERENT documents.

**With cloud functions, I could do something like 'users/{userId}/{collection1}/{docId}/{collectionToListen}/{docAdded}'**

How can I implement the same logic but directly with Cloud Firestore? 
Using the .onSnapshot method.

PS: I want to listen to new DOCS at the end of the wildcard path, not new collections.

Comment: It seems what you are asking is 'how do I watch for changes in a collection of documents'. In this case you could add a listener to collection1, which will notify you of any changes within doc1, doc2 etc. Since you know doc1, doc2 you could just added listeners to those specific documents which will notify you of any changes within each. The question and use case is a bit unclear - maybe providing a bit more info would help.

Comment: @Jay Nope. I want to listen for the "docAdded". 
If I listen collection1, i'll only get doc1, doc2, doc3 changes.
But I want to go deeper.

As I said, With cloud functions, I could do something like 'users/{userId}/{collection1}/{docId}/{collectionToListen}/{docAdded}'

This will notify me of ANY docAdded in this structure (doc in subcollection of doc in collection of user of collection)

Comment: If you look at your comment, you're specifying the path to listen to in your cloud function; *users/userId/collection1/docId/collectionToListen/docAdded* so event would happen for any added in /collectionToListen. But not in /collectionToListen2. So you would specify the same path in Firestore and add the listener. Keep in mind that if you use that path in a cloud function and something is added to *users/userId/collection2/docId/collectionToListen/docAdded* you would not be notified because your not listening on a path that has collection2 in it, only collection1.

Comment: I think you're not getting it brother. I can't specify the path because there'll be more added!
The collection1 will be always be the same for every user (same name), but inside that collection, an user can have 10 docs, another user may have only 1, another one may have 60.
If I listenf or changes inside collection1, i'll get the new docs created, but i won't get the "docAdded" neither its parent collection.

Comment: I do get it but the question has been asked before and the answer that @dougstevenson posted to the duplicate question is accurate. However, it's unclear why you don't simply add listeners on doc1/collectionToListen, doc2/collectionToListen etc. Additionally, the structure is pretty deep so you may want to consider denormalizing your data to bring it to a higher level. Check out [denormalizing is normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) - while it's old content it's still very valid and there are a few links for further reading as well.